# how to call two submit buttons in spring form, one calls j_spring_security_check and another one calling controller method

Tags: spring, spring-security

How to call two submit buttons in spring form,
one button calls j_spring_security_check and another button one calling controller method.
following is login form

```
                <form action="../../j_spring_security_check" method="post" >

         <div class="right">
          <ul>
            <li>
              <spring:message code="label.userName" text="UserName" />
              <input id="j_username" name="j_username" type="text" />
        <form:errors path="firstName" cssclass="error">    </form:errors>
            </li>
            <li>
              <spring:message code="label.password" text="Password" />
              <input id="j_password" name="j_password" type="password" />
              <form:errors path="password" cssclass="error"></form:errors>
            </li>
            <li>

              <input type="submit" value="Login" />&nbsp;&nbsp;


            </li>
          </ul>
        </div>
        </form> 
             <form action="/portal/main/resetForgetPassword" method="POST">
                 <input type="submit" value="ForgetPassword">  
              </form>
```

thanks advance

Comment: In Spring Security before going to your controller method it will call j_spring_security_check url which is intercepted so i guess no need of having two submit buttons.

Comment: @Shoaib Chikate: yes but in my form page one login button and another forgot password button will be there.so when i click on forgot password it not redirecting to the controller...

Comment: Then it is redirecting to whom??

Comment: @Shoaib Chikate:<form action="../../j_spring_security_check" method="post" > <form action="/portal/main/forgetPassword" method="post"> these are my actions . i am clicking on the forgetpassword button. but it not going to the controller..please help me...

Answer (score 0):

I guess your problem is that for every URL it is going to Security form of spring.

So you need to permit for some url so that it should not go to j_spring_security_check

You can do this in the security.xml (whatever may be the name of that file).

```
   <intercept-url pattern="/portal/main/forgetPassword*" access="permitAll" />
   <intercept-url pattern="/*" access="hasRole('ROLE_ADMIN_ASSUMED')">
```

And also in your html code

```
  <a href="/portal/main/resetForgetPassword">Forget Password</a>
```

Comment: thanks ur reply.. i tried this way but it not going to controller .. i am using tiles frame work and spring ,jsp

Comment: i am added my login form..please check.

Comment: Try to give link forget password as <a href="/portal/main/resetForgetPassword">Forget Password</a>